# XSLT template to replace string with string Including HTML Tags

Tags: html, xslt-2.0

I have this template to replace once string with another:

```
<xsl:template name="X">
<xsl:param name="field"/>
<xsl:param name="target"/>
<xsl:param name="change"/>
<xsl:value-of select='replace($field, $target, $change )' />  
</xsl:template>
```

This is how I am calling it:

```
<xsl:call-template name="X">
<xsl:with-param name="field" select="artist"/>
<xsl:with-param name="target" select="'\\n'"/>
<xsl:with-param name="change" select="'&#10;'"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

This works in most cases except for the case demonstrated here.
I am trying to replace the string "\n"  with a HTML line break **<br>** or **<br />**.
I want an actual new line not the tag visible in the output.
I know that it is matching on the **\n** but I can not make the line break happen.
I either get a literal **<br>** in the output or nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change your approach. Your template is using `replace()` which works with strings. You want to replace with markup. I'd use `xsl:analyze-string` instead:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="break"><br/></xsl:variable>
            
      <xsl:call-template name="X">
        <xsl:with-param name="field" select="artist"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="target" select="'\n'"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="change" select="$break"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template name="X">
      <xsl:param name="field"/>
      <xsl:param name="target"/>
      <xsl:param name="change"/>
      <!-- <xsl:value-of select='replace($field, $target, $change )' />-->
      <xsl:analyze-string select="$field" regex="{$target}">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
          <xsl:sequence select="$change"/>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
      </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:template> 
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Fantastic!   it works for strings and <br>!
Can you tell me what the curly braces do in this case? `{$target}`

Comment: the curly braces are an Attribute Value Template https://www.w3.org/TR/2021/REC-xslt20-20210330/#attribute-value-templates. The `@regex` was expecting a literal string, so in order to resolve the value of `$target` needed the AVT, otherwise it would use `$target` as the regex.

Comment: I'm also trying to replace an actual new line in the input with **<br />**  I tried matching on **&#xa;** and **&#xd;** but neither seem to match.

Comment: Post a simplified example of your input XML and XSLT in a qustion.